# Trying to add Newline in Menu item

Tags: menus, dashboard

I'm trying to add newline from the dashboard Menu, so it looks like this:

First Line

Second Line

Instead of:

First Line Second Line

I've seen post saying you can just add the html tag `<br />` and it will work, but that is not the case for me. I'm not sure what I'm missing:
[image]

Comment: if it doesn't work, what does it do instead? Keep in mind a lot of themes won't work with that, and questions here are for programming

Comment: it shows exactly whats in the navigation label. I didn't realize this was a theme issue. I guess the Label string is going through some sort of `esc_attr` then?